training of the temporal fusion transformer model
I have a question with regard to the training process of the temporal fusion transformer model:
In case the dataset is comprised of multiple time series, how would minimizing the loss function work? Does it try to minimize the loss for each time series individually? Or does it try to minimize the loss for all the time series together?
